# Insert data in mysql from multiple sources

Tags: mysql

I want to insert  values from different sources. For example

```
insert into a (('id','name','add'),'college')
select from b where id = 1,'abc'
```

Here there is no timestamp field in table b

Comment: Your code makes very little sense. Can you tell us exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am inserting trying to insert 3 fields from table a and default fourth field value.I know i can set defalut value in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your query as follows:

```
insert into a (id, name, add, college) 
select id, name, add, 'abc' from b where id = 1
```

With this query, the 4th column in `a` will be assigned a constant value of `'abc'`.

Comment: There are only three fields in table b.As i mentioned ealier there is no college field in table b

Comment: @RaviVishwakarma: yes, that's why the query assigns a constant value (`'abc'`) to the 4th column of `a`.